How to spellout the decimal part in french using ICU4J?
I try to use ICU 4J to spellout numbers in french. I have an issue where the decimal part is spelled out digit by digit, which is a bit weird for some numbers. For instance 4.05 is formatted as "quatre virgule zéro cinq", which is ok, but 4.25 is formatted as "quatre virgule deux cinq" instead of "quatre virgule vingt-cinq". This is how I use the library :
var formatter = new RuleBasedNumberFormat(Locale.FRENCH, RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT);
formatter.format(4.05); // "quatre virgule zéro cinq" -> OK
formatter.format(4.25); // "quatre virgule deux cinq" -> KO

What should I do to make it spell the decimal part more naturally ?

Oh man you will have to build a custom formatter to make it work, Godspeed!  One for each type of segment, such as you are dealing with a "quarter" in one of the examples above.  For each, alternate name, you will need to define how it should handle it.
